# Grails 3 set-version replacement

Tags: grails, jenkins, gradle, build.gradle, grails3

On our Grails 2 projects we used the set-version command line option.  I do not see that command available in Grails 3.  I do see the version property in the gradle.build file.  Did that replace the app.version from the application.properties?  I build our projects using Jenkins and SVN repository.  What is the best way to handle setting the version parameter for Grails 3 to the SVN revision number.  Below is a section of the build.gradle file, that includes the version property, which is generated when creating a Grail 3 application.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.0.M2"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "appName"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
```

In grails 2 the property was called app.version (from the application.properties file) and could be referenced in gsp using the following:

```
Revision: <g:meta name="app.version"/>
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer.  The question was edited in a way that makes it a wholly different question.  I think that is bad practice and you should have posted a new question.

Comment: As written right now, the question is really about 2 separate issues.  One is setting the version number based on the SVN version and the other is how to retrieve the version number in a GSP.

Comment: I sorry you misunderstood my question.  I did edit the question make it clear it was not about the grails version.  It was always about the set-version command from Grails 2 which changed the app.version in application.properties.  I did add the g:meta tag detail since that is the way you access the value and the name has change in Grails 3 and some of the docs still reference the old name.

Comment: I would be happy to delete my question and repost the question if that would be a better practice.

Comment: "I would be happy to delete my question and repost the question if that would be a better practice." - Deleting this question and posting another one just like it wouldn't improve anything.  You should just leave this one.  The better practice would have been to leave the original question in tact because it was a valid question.  You changed it to a whole separate question, thus wasting the time of everyone who spent time answering the first question.

Comment: "I sorry you misunderstood my question. I did edit the question make it clear it was not about the grails version." - The original question included "What is the best way to handle setting the version parameter for Grails 3" and made no mention of SVN or Jenkins.  That is why I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trail and error using Grails 3.2.0.M2 I was successful using the Gradle plugin to Jenkins.  I was able to use the Environment variable SVN_REPOSITORY so I edited the build.gradle to:

```
version System.getenv('SVN_REVISION')
```

Also I noticed in the generated index.gsp that the property name for the version value using the g:meta tag library has changed.  The name has changed to info.app.version so here is an example how to use the value now:

```
<g:meta name="info.app.version"/>
```

Also for the grails version the name has also changed:

```
<g:meta name="info.app.grailsVersion"/>
```